# What's the Opposite of $("p + p") in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This sounds like a pretty simple question, but I can't find anything in the jQuery documentation. Basically, I need to know what the opposite of jQuery's [Next Adjacent Selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/) is.

Here's what I have for the Next Adjacent Selector:

`$("#newsSlider p.active + p").addClass("active");`

And here's what I tried to reverse that:

`$("#newsSlider p.active - p").addClass("active");`

It doesn't work, obviously, so what can I do to reverse the Next Adjacent Selector thing? If you need more information, let me know.

Comment: Why would `$("#newsSlider p.active - p")` work? Are you just guessing at random syntax?

Comment: @popnoodles: Yes. The `elem + elem` is a valid Selectors API selector.

Comment: There is no opposite of Next Adjacent Selector because it's not necessary, the Next Adjacent Selector will find all elements that match the pattern.

Comment: @popnoodles: It is? Guessing at syntax is a poor approach to problem solving.

Comment: After looking around the web for the opposite of what I had for the first bit of code, I just guessed what it would logically be. Obviously just guessing syntax won't work 95% of the time, but I figured it was worth a shot.

Comment: @popnoodles, no, [a logical stab in the dark is reading the api to see what's available.](http://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: @popnoodles, ***that's exactly my point*** why guess when you could be using *actual logic*?

Comment: No, you didn't make a point. you made an assertion which is not true:  "a logical stab in the dark is reading the api to see what's available." They are totally opposite things.

Comment: @popnoodles: Setting aside your discussion about the phrase "stab in the dark", certainly you agree that trying some random syntax without basis and then when it fails running to someone to ask for help is not a good approach to problem solving, right?

Comment: @thesystem What's the point of a dictionary if you don't know how to spell a word in the first place? How do you begin when you need to find the correct spelling? OP guessed it. OP found it didn't work. OP asked about it. OP was given the answer within minutes. Is there a problem with peer to peer knowledge sharing? Do you believe, instead, one has to write it out in the form of documentation for another to seek it? If so why does Stack Overflow exist?

Comment: It's not like I just completely gave up after trying one thing. If you read above, I did try searching around, but I didn't come across `.prev()` because I was searching for things like "opposite of `p + p`: not "opposite of `.next();`"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for `.prev()`, the opposite of `.next()`?

```
$("#newsSlider p.active").prev('p').addClass("active");
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe it was that simple. Thanks, I'll accept as soon as it'll let me.

Comment: If you were to emulate the desired syntax, the `'p'` would be necessary in the `.prev()` call just in case there's a `p.active` element whose previous element sibling is not a `p`.